# How to eliminate zero after decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a code to get the numbers which passes my calculation and gives output only if the said output is an integer. But the answers always get a 0 after the decimal point(208.0) and so I am unable to filter out the rest of false outputs which are floats.
How can we print outputs with just a trailing zero and eliminate the rest or convert the float with just a trailing zero to integer so that it can be filtered out.

```
a = 200
while a<300:
 b=a+(a*4.0/100)
 if type(b)==int:
  print a
 a=a+1
```

This code now prints nothing as there is no integer output

Comment: Depending on how concerned you are about accuracy or how many digits after floating point you intend to retain there are multiple solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `float.is_integer`:

```
a = 200
while a < 300:
    b = a + (a * 4.0 / 100)
    if b.is_integer():
        print int(b)
    else:
        print b
    if type(b) == int:
        print a
    a = a + 1
```

Or try:

```
a = 200
while a < 300:
    b = a + (a * 4.0 / 100)
    if int(b) == b:
        print int(b)
    else:
        print b
    if type(b) == int:
        print a
    a = a + 1
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't need to print b(line 7) because it printed all float op.

Answer (score 1):

Got the code from @U12-Forward ,shortened it a bit.

```
while a < 300:
    b = a + (a * 4.0 / 100)
    if b.is_integer():
        print a
        print int(b)
    a = a + 1
```

Now does the job!